# What kinds of browser redirects are supported in Android?

Tags: browser, javascript, android

I recently developed a web app which used the JavaScript window.location property to redirect the browser. This worked fine on PC browsers, but did not function at all on both of the Android browsers I tried it on.

The unsupported browsers were: Browser (built-in) and Dolphin Browser.

I discovered that location.replace() does work on these browsers, as well as on the PC.

Is this Android limitation documented anywhere, and what other redirect methods are available on the Android platform?

Comment: You might get better/different responses at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Reading the FAQ a bit, I think you're right; I'd not object to this question being moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For raw JavaScript redirect, location.replace() works.

The more robust way of redirecting would be to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), as this should handle platform-specific cases under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP redirects seem to work fine in the Dolphin browser HD.

Comment: Does PHP do that through an HTTP header?  It would make sense since HTTP headers should work in every decent browser.